# UIButtons in ChildView controllers not firing

Tags: swift3, uibutton, uipageviewcontroller, childviewcontroller

so i have added three child view controllers to a pageViewController which all scroll fine and I can see the 3 child view controllers fine in the simulator but for some reason none of the buttons in my child view controllers work. Here is the code of my pageViewController / rootViewController

import UIKit

class RootPageViewController: UIPageViewController, UIPageViewControllerDataSource, UIPageViewControllerDelegate {

```
lazy var viewControllerList:[UIViewController] = {

    let sb = UIStoryboard(name: "customKeyboardStoryboard", bundle: nil)

    let vc1 = sb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "peopleVC") as! KeyboardViewController
    let vc2 = sb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "animalsVC") as! animalsViewController
    let vc3 = sb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "foodVC") as! KeyboardViewController

    self.addChildViewController(vc1)
    self.addChildViewController(vc2)
    self.addChildViewController(vc3)

    vc1.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
    vc2.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
    vc3.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true

    vc1.willMove(toParentViewController: nil)
    vc2.willMove(toParentViewController: nil)
    vc3.willMove(toParentViewController: nil)


    // self.view.addSubview(vc1.view)
    // self.view.addSubview(vc2.view)
    // self.view.addSubview(vc3.view)


    vc1.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
    vc2.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
    vc3.didMove(toParentViewController: self)



    return [vc1, vc2, vc3]


}()




override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    self.dataSource = self
    self.delegate = self
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.


    if let firstViewController = viewControllerList.first{
    self.setViewControllers([firstViewController], direction: .forward, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }


}

func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {

    guard let vcIndex = viewControllerList.index(of: viewController) else {return nil}

    let previousIndex = vcIndex - 1

    guard previousIndex >= 0 else {return nil}

    guard viewControllerList.count > previousIndex else {return nil}

    return viewControllerList[previousIndex]
}

func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {

    guard let vcIndex = viewControllerList.index(of: viewController) else {return nil}

    let nextIndex = vcIndex + 1

    guard viewControllerList.count != nextIndex else {return nil}

    guard viewControllerList.count > nextIndex else {return nil}


    return viewControllerList[nextIndex]
}

private func setupPageControl() {
    let appearance = UIPageControl.appearance()
    appearance.pageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.gray
    appearance.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.white
    appearance.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGray

}

func presentationCount(for pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int {
    setupPageControl()
    return self.viewControllerList.count
}

func presentationIndex(for pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int {
    return 0
}



override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


/*
// MARK: - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/
```

}

And here is one of my child view controllers code - I just have one button linked to it at the moment to try and get the buttons working

import UIKit

class animalsViewController: UIInputViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {

```
@IBOutlet var animalsView: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var animalsCollectonView: UICollectionView!

var animals = ["",""]


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    animalsCollectonView.delegate = self
    animalsCollectonView.dataSource = self
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}


func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
   return animals.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let animalsCell = animalsCollectonView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CustomCell1", for: indexPath) as! CustomCell1

    animalsCell.myImage.setTitle(animals[indexPath.row], for: UIControlState.normal)

    animalsCell.myImage.tag = indexPath.row

    return animalsCell

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


@IBAction func nextKeyboard(_ sender: Any) {

    advanceToNextInputMode()

}

/*
// MARK: - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/
```

}

Comment: post the code of your child view controller

Comment: hi there samarth, posted the one of the child view code above - just added one button at the moment to try and get it working - "advanceToNextInputMode()" @SamarthKejriwal

Comment: where is the function `advanceToNextInputMode()
`

Comment: i just have that entered under the IBAction on the child view controller @SamarthKejriwal its worked fine before I added the pageViewController, but now the button doesn't work since adding the pageViewCOntroller

Comment: what do u want to do with your action button,do you want to go to other vc by clicking on it, please post the `advanceToNextInputMode() ` method

Comment: and do change the relation of your IBAction to type UIButton ,by deleting the IBAction method and draging your button again to the view controller and select the type as UIButton

Comment: no, the advanceToNextInputMode() is an inbuilt swift function that takes the user to the next keyboard when they tap the globe icon on a custom keyboard. None of the buttons on my child view controllers work right now because there must be something over riding the buttons since I added the pageViewController - I just can't seem to press any of the buttons in my child view controllers. so it must be something to do with my child view code being over ridden by the parent pageViewController but I can't work it out @SamarthKejriwal

Comment: read my last comment

Comment: ok thanks so I have dragged the button again and used UIButton so it is now a IBOutlet instead. How then to associate the advanceToNextInputMode() with that UIButton now  @SamarthKejriwal

Comment: No you didnt got it , firstly clear this IBAction and remove the connection of this button from the connection inspector  and then drag the button again and then select the connection as IBAction with the type as UIButton and then try it again

Comment: ok thanks, I did that - when i tap the button it just flashes but does not complete the moveToNextInputMode() action. All the buttons in all my child view controllers just flash when I tap them and don't actually execute their actions @SamarthKejriwal